# I can't see "pgagent job" in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin, pgagent

DB Server : PostgreSQL 14.8

## CREATE EXTENSION pgagent ;

## CREATE LANGAUGE plpgsql ;

## \dx

```
             List of installed extensions
```

Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
pgagent | 4.2     | pgagent    | A PostgreSQL job scheduler
plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language

## \dn

List of schemas
Name   |  Owner
---------+----------
pgagent | postgres
public  | postgres

All of these cases are confirmed as normal, but pgadmin does not see pgagent job for that db.

[image]

This is pgadmin4 v7.1.